# trouble simplifying polynomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have been presented with the following polynomial expression$$(x-5)^4+x(x-5)^3$$It is given that the polynomial is equal to$$(x-5)^3(x-5+4x)$$my apologies for lack of information however it is because I do not know where to begin with solving this question. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's not possible because of the degree of polynomials

Comment: What are you trying to find? Also, those two polynomials are definitely not equal... one has a much higher degree than the other.

Comment: The question has been edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that $ac + bc = (a+b)c$.  This is the distributive property in reverse.

Next, remember that $a^{b+1}=a\cdot a^b$ by properties of exponents.

You have

$$\begin{array}{r|l}(x-5)^4+x(x-5)^3&\text{original expression}\\
(x-5)\cdot (x-5)^3+x(x-5)^3&\text{by factoring out one copy of}~ (x-5) \text{ from the left}\\
((x-5)+x)\cdot (x-5)^3&\text{by distributive property}\\(2x-5)\cdot (x-5)^3&\text{by addition and removal of unnecessary parentheses}\end{array}$$

This is not equal to $(x-5+4x)(x-5)^3$ except in the case that both sides are equal to zero, which occurs precisely when $x=5$ or when $(2x-5)$ is equal to $(5x-5)$ which occurs when $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By factoring out $(x-5)^3$ from both terms, we get
$$
(x-5)^3[(x-5)+x]=(x-5)^3(2x-5).
$$
This doesn't agree with the stated equality...